# Plank dock doesn't want to start

Tags: plank

I was trying to install the dock plank but when I finished installing it and tried to start it from the app menu it did not open it, so I tried to start it from the terminal but it reported the following error`[CRITICAL 18:56:34.209013] [AbstractMain:255] Only X11 environments are supported.` could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

ok i've solved it, i was using wayland and not Xorg and i simply switched to Xorg, you have just to go on login screen and press on the bottom-right button and then click on "Ubuntu on Xorg" and then it should work.